# Height: Fill whole viewport but scroll if neccessary

Tags: html, css

I want to divide the viewport into 3 rows:

1.) header

2.) content

3.) footer

The header and footer have a fixed height while the content should have a flexible height according to its inner text. The rules should be:

1.) If the height of header + content + footer is **smaller** than the viewport, the height of the content should be increased so that the height of header + content + footer match the height of the viewport.

2.) If the height of header + content + footer is **bigger** than the viewport, then the vertical scrollbar should appear.

I thought this was easy, but using height:100% on html, body and wrapper doesn't work with rule 2.) Using min-height:100% on html, body and wrapper doesn't work with rule 1.)

Any idea how to make this work?

```css
html,
body,
wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your `CSS`.

```
html,
body,
wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

The issue is that `wrapper` should be `.wrapper`. Furthermore, don't bother setting `100%` height on `html`, `body`, `.wrapper`, etc. All you need to worry about is `.wrapper`. Simply set `min-height: 100vh` on it and you'll be done. I'm zeroing out the default margins provided by the browser, but that is optional and unrelated to your question.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;      /* <-- All that's needed */
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank. Yes, my example got an error *blush*, but it didn't work in my source-code as well till I replace min-height:100% with min-height:100vh. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

is this are you looking for?

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;     // fixed height
  margin: 0;        //removed default spacing
  padding: 0;       //removed default spacing
  border: 0;        //removed default spacing
  overflow: hidden; // removed scroll from html and body
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;     // fixed height
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow: auto;   // enabled scroll bar
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: A bit different what I thought but clever as well. I will check if I take your solution so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg3nr0vj/)

```
html, body, .wrapper {
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0
}
.wrapper {
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.header, .footer {
 height:20px;
 background-color:#a0a0a0;
 }

.content {
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set flex to none for header and footer. For content set the flex to auto.
Below is the complete modified code.

**CSS**

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper  {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;   
}

.header, .footer {
    flex:none;
    background-color:#a0a0a0;
    color:white;

}
.content {
    flex:auto;  
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>

    </div>
</body>
```